# How To Upgrade & Wipe my M1 Mac?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, install, apple-silicon

I have a 2020 MacBook Air (M1) I've used for a while, which is why I want to do a clean install of macOS Monterey once it becomes available. I know on intel macs pressing ⌥⌘R will re-install the latest OS available, but I don't see an option for it in M1. (It is the original recovery page). Is there a way I can clean install macOS *and* wipe it at once? (preferably not using a bootable USB) Or will I need to upgrade first and then wipe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**How to upgrade?**

Apple's OS installers are designed to install in the place of an existing OS installation. The OS system files are on a separate, read-only partition that is cryptographically 'sealed'. Only Apple's installers can change the files there.

So there is absolutely no benefit for the OS; no 'cleaning' that gets done by wiping the OS before re-installing the OS. If you then restore all your software and user preferences from Time Machine, then you have removed any possible benefit.

Secondly, you've only had the thing for a few months! What is it that you are hoping to 'clean'? Cache files? Third-party apps? User settings? These can all be deleted individually  without deleting everything.

'Nuke and pave' is time-consuming; teaches you nothing about how to maintain your computer; and unnecessary.

*(By contrast, I haven't done a clean install in c. 15 years, and have cloned my system disk to each new Mac without any performance problems or other issues.)*

Comment: I'm not trying to wipe my MacBook because of my files, but I want to *re-install* the OS because it occasionally crashes (cpu panic). But this happens less than once a month (which is why I'm not that concerned) but I thought it would be nice to do a clean install of Monterey instead of wiping & updating twice.

Comment: @JongwooLee Then just re-install the OS. No wiping necessary. Certainly no need to wipe twice!! The panic might be a bug in the OS, or it might be something else.